# How to record all audio generated from my app (might from AVPlayer or others) in iOS? (not mic)

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, audiounit, audiotoolbox

There are many audio generated from my app, the sources could be `AVPlayer`, `AudioUnit`, etc. I want to record all the audio(not from mic because that would record user voice) into a single file. Is there any way to get the final mixed audio data before sent to the audio playback hardware?

I've tried `AudioUnit`, and [**The Amazing Audio Engine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430307/record-all-sounds-generated-by-my-app-in-a-audio-file-not-from-mic). However it could only record audio played by `AudioUnit`.

Also read the [**MTAudioProcessingTap**](https://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/), but it has to inject some code into `AVPlayer`, and seems complicated to mix all the audio.

Comment: I'm wondering if what was presented at the WWDC this year regarding AVAudioEngine and new rendering options might not help (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/501/).

Comment: @filaton thanks, i would give it a try.